# Cannot subscript a value of type String:AnyObject

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift3, swift4, completionhandler

I am making an expense tracking app and here I have some code in which I want to return an array with dates as Strings and their expenses as items of those dates so that I can use the dates as headers for tableViews and the expenses as cells in those sections. However I get the following error in the last line.

```
items.append(groupedExpensesSorted[eachKey])
```

Cannot subscript a value of type '[(key: String, value: [Expense])]' with an index of type 'String'

But I don't understand why it is happening. Could someone please help me?

```
class GroupingOperations: NSObject {

var expenses = [Expense]()
var expensePerCollection = [Expense]()

public func getExpenses(collection: String, completionHandler: @escaping([[Expense]], [String]) -> Void){
    self.expenses = CoreDataHelper.retrieveExpenses()//.sorted(by: { $0.modificationDate as! Date > $1.modificationDate as! Date})
    for eachExpense in expenses{
        if eachExpense.collection == collection{
            expensePerCollection.append(eachExpense)
        }
    }

    for eachCollectionExpense in expensePerCollection{
        print("Name: \(String(describing: eachCollectionExpense.name)) - Date: \(String(describing: eachCollectionExpense.modificationDate))")
    }
    let sortedExpensePerCollection = expensePerCollection.sorted(by: { $0.modificationDate as! Date > $1.modificationDate as! Date})
    var groupedExpenses = Dictionary(grouping: sortedExpensePerCollection, by: {($0.modificationDate! as Date).convertToJSONDate()})

    let keys = Array(groupedExpenses.keys)
    var items:[[Expense]] = []
    let groupedExpensesSorted = groupedExpenses.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
    for eachKey in keys {
        items.append(groupedExpensesSorted[eachKey])
    }
    completionHandler(items, keys)
    //let sortedKeys = keys.sorted(by: {$0 > $1})
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear.

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[(key: String, value: [Expense])]' with an index of type 'String'

means what it says: *An array of tuples cannot be subscripted by a (string) key*

---

- `groupedExpenses` is a dictionary (`var groupedExpenses = Dictionary(grouping:...`)
- Applying *sorted* to a dictionary (which is actually a contradiction in terms) converts the dictionary into an **array** of (key, value) tuples.
- An array is subscripted by index, not by key. That's what the error message states.

Comment: So how would it be fixed, as I need it to be sorted by dates.